# Edit/fork packages installed via package-install

Tags: package

I would like to make a few changes to a package installed via `package-install`. What's the canonical way to do so?

I understand that it would probably involve:

1. Uninstalling the package via `list-packages`. (Is this necessary?)
2. Place the package files manually somewhere under `~/.emacs.d` (e.g. by cloning the Git repository)
3. Tell Emacs to load the package from the new location. (How?)

Comment: Whenever I find the need to modify a package, I can usually achieve it with advice. Is that a possibility for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Uninstalling the package via list-packages. (Is this necessary?)

Not at all. Just make sure that the git clone is ahead of ELPA on `load-path`.

> Place the package files manually somewhere under ~/.emacs.d (e.g. by cloning the Git repository)
>   Tell Emacs to load the package from the new location. (How?)

I have a dedicated `git/` directory in my `site-lisp`. And just clone there. This code will put all packages in `git/` ahead of ELPA on the `load-path`:

```cl
(package-initialize)
(let ((emacs-git (expand-file-name "git/" emacs-d)))
  (mapc (lambda (x)
          (add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name x emacs-git)))
        (delete ".." (directory-files emacs-git))))
```

Comment: A lot of time has passed so this may only be a little incompatibility, but: what is the variable `emacs-d`? I can't find it on my system

Comment: It's a custom variable I defined that points to a directory where the "git" folder is. You can adapt something similar to your config.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to use the package manager for this (which is entirely reasonable -- it will take care of byte-compilation, ensure all the autoloads are processed, etc), then:

- Copy the package (somewhere that isn't in your Emacs `load-path`) and make whatever changes you wish to make.
- If it is a simple package built from a single `.el` file (ignoring `*.elc`, `*-pkg.el`, and `*-autoloads.el` files):

  - Update the version string in the `.el` file.
  - Invoke `package-install-file` on the modified `.el` file.
- If it is a complex package built from multiple files:

  - Update the version string in the `*-pkg.el` file
  - If you're running Emacs 25+, invoke `package-install-file` on the directory.
  - If you're running Emacs 24, create a tar file of the directory (include the directory itself; not just its contents), and invoke `package-install-file` on the tar file.

You should be able to safely delete the unnecessary files from your modified source for the package (e.g. `*.elc`, `*-autoloads.el`, and for the simple package case, `*-pkg.el`).

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Packaging` for more information.

Comment: I've accepted abo-abo's answer as it seems to allow contributing changes upstream the easiest, but this answer is interesting too. I would like to ask, though - is running `package-install-file` necessary every time I want an edit to take effect? And, will the package manager clobber my installed package when the upstream package is updated?

Comment: Emacs does not *automatically* install newer releases of any package -- it's not going to clobber a package unless you ask it to. You would need to run `package-install-file` every time, unless you took to editing and re-compiling the installed versions under `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directly (but I don't think that's what you were wanting to do).

Comment: Note that if a package is derived from a git repository, it's fairly likely that you can check that out and use it as your target for `package-install-file`.

Answer (score 1):

Or install `use-package`, and explicitly supply the load path this way:

```
(use-package example
  :load-path "/directory/of/your/package")
```